# creating a class for graphics in C++ using SDL

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sdl

I'm trying to create a game window for a cave story clone in C++, so first, I create the header file below, after that, I  went to create the class file. When I finish the class I kept receiving the error that the argument type is incomplete with a parameter of type sdl_window and sdl_render. If anyone could help me figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Graphics.h

```
#ifndef GRAPHICS.h

#define GRAPHICS.h

struct SDL_window;
struct SDL_render;

class Graphics {
    public:
        Graphics();
        ~Graphics();
    private:
        SDL_window* window = NULL;
        SDL_render* render = NULL;
};

#endif
```

Graphics.cpp

```
#include <SDL.h>

#include "graphics.h"


/* Graphics class
* Holds all information dealing with graphics for the game
*/

Graphics::Graphics() {
    SDL_CreateWindowAndRenderer(640, 480, 0, &window, &render);
    SDL_SetWindowTitle(window, "Cavestory");
}

Graphics::~Graphics() {
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
}
```

Comment: @JohnnyMopp that's incorrect. He can forward declare the structures and reference a pointer without a full definition.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't mean `struct SDL_Window`? Your casing in the forward declares doesn't match the actual SDL structs.

Comment: @AustinBrunkhorst Ok. Missed that.

Comment: On a side note, why not use [SFML](https://www.sfml-dev.org/)? It provides essentially the same functionality as SDL but is written in C++ instead of C.

Comment: @TimStraubinger I actually didn't know about SFML my friend told me about SDL, so I was giving it a try. I'll look into it, thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you are declaring your own types unrelated to SDL types. Rewrite class to use appropriate types:

```
#include <SDL.h>

class Graphics {
  public:
    Graphics();
    ~Graphics();
  private:
    SDL_Window *   window = nullptr;
    SDL_Renderer * render = nullptr;
};
```